# Magento 2 Add Custom Image Uploader in Admin Product Edit Form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am struggling with strange and very common issue with Custom Image Uploader in Admin. I just need to add a custom image uploader in the Product add/edit form and to save the particular image respective to that product as custom attribute. But, When i am trying to upload the file it always gives error "The file was not uploaded.". Here is my code.

Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="Custom" frontName="Custom">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <fieldset name="magenest">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Specification Image</item>
               <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
               <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.magenest</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
<field name="specification_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Specification Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="Custom/product_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Vendor\Module\Setup\UpgradeData.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var eavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetup;
    
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory        
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;        
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
           
            $this->addProductImageAttribute();
        }
    }

    public function addProductImageAttribute()
    {
        $this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'specification_image',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'backend'      => '',
                'frontend'     => '',
                'label'        => 'Specification Image',
                'input'        => 'image',
                'global'       => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default'      => '',
                'searchable'   => false,
                'filterable'   => false,
                'comparable'   => false,
                'unique'       => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'group'        => 'General Information'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Ffc\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Image\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ProductImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\ProductImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/product</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/product</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="allowedMimeTypes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>    
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Image\Upload.php

```
<?php        

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    
    protected $imageUploader;    
    
    private $uploaderFactory;
    
    protected $mediaDirectory;
        
    protected $storeManager;
        
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        
    protected $logger;

    protected $imageUploaders;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger            
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->logger = $logger;            
    }

    
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::product');
    }
        
    public function execute()
    {
        try {            
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('specification_image');                
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

I didn't find anything in the error log. I tried every possible way to find the root cause of the problem but couldn't. I thought this problem might be due to not available of the MIME type. So i added "allowedMimeTypes" argument in di.xml but that also didn't work out.

I followed the same way to add custom Image Uploader in Admin Category Edit Form and It's working perfectly without any problem. But I don't know why it's not working with Product. Apart from solving this issue, please also guide me how to save this image with product as it's custom attribute value in database.

I appreciate every help possible. Thank you!